# An APK cannot have a filename with (NUL, CR, LF) characters

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm working on a mobile app with Cordova and Ionic. I'm trying to upload the generated APK to Google Play Store. When I upload the APK I'm getting the following error: **"An APK cannot have a filename with (NUL, CR, LF) characters."**

The APK filename doesn't have either of those characters.

I've already tried cleaning the project, deleted platform folder, and building it again.

This is the environment information:

```
cli packages: (/opt/node/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
    Node              : v8.9.4
    npm               : 5.6.0 
    OS                : Linux 4.9

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /opt/android

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.app.name" version="1.01.02" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>AppName</name>
    <description>
    </description>
    <author email="author@gmail.com" href="http://google.com/">
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="file://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="tel:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="mailto:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <framework src="com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
            <string>xxx.</string>
        </edit-config>
        <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription">
            <string>xxx</string>
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="20" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="9000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.28:8101" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.13:8101" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.100:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.28:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.31:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.29:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.12:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.20:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.1.33:8100" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.7.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="4.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="5.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="1.7.4">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="xxxx" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="appName" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="7.1.2">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" spec="5.3.0">
        <variable name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID" value="xxxx" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot" spec="0.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated" spec="2.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="2.1.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" spec="^3.0.1">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="android" spec="6.3.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.5" />
</widget>
```

Do you have any clue of what I am missing here?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your `config.xml` file?

Comment: @andypotato I've updated the question with the config.xml info. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that the `<widget id="...">`  tags like `<name>`, `<description>` and `<author>` don't contain any line breaks any other of the characters the Play Store is complaining about. Afterwards use `ionic platform remove android` and `ionic platform add android` which will recreate the Android project files (just changing `config.xml` won't). Finally try to rebuild and submit your app.

Comment: Thanks, @andypotato for your response. I checked every tag and remove all the characters that might generate the issue. However, it didn't solve the issue. I also checked the Manifest file but didn't find anything that may cause the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `Icon?` file generated by MacOS when a folder has a specific icon.
It's name is actually `Icon\r`, with \r being the carriage return.

In order to find and remove these files run the following command:

```
find . -name "Icon?" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have met this issue caused by `._Icon` file generated by MacOS, find in your project these files and remove it.